# Calling a webservice that uses ISO-8859-1 encoding from WCF

Tags: .net, wcf

I am trying to call a webservice using WCF that uses the following encoding:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
```

I cannot change the encoding for this webservice.  I have generated a wcf proxy and when I try and call the proxy, I get the following error:

> FailedSystem.ServiceModel.ProtocolException:
>   The content type text/xml;
>   charset=ISO-8859-1 of the response
>   message does not match the content
>   type of the binding (text/xml;
>   charset=utf-8). If using a custom
>   encoder, be sure that the
>   IsContentTypeSupported method is
>   implemented properly.

Has anyone any idea how I call a webservice that is not UTF-8 using wcf?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You cannot do this out of the box in WCF - unfortunately.

I faced the same issue, and came up with a custom binding (either in config or in code) that you can use. It's based on HTTP transport, and if that's of help to you, I could post the custom config here, or send you a link to the C# code for the binding.

This [MSDN page here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751486.aspx) shows how to create a "CustomTextEncoder" which can support more than utf-8, utf-16 and unicode encodings. It includes full sample source code and was very useful for me to get things going.

This [blog post here](http://msmvps.com/blogs/paulomorgado/archive/2007/04/25/wcf-text-message-encoding-and-iso-8859-1-encoding.aspx) shows some additional things to take into account when trying to get that custom text encoder to work properly.

Hope that helps.

Marc

**UPDATE:**
Based on the Microsoft sample I mentioned above for a CustomTextEncoder, you can easily create a custom binding with a ISO-8859-1 text message encoding - just use this snippet of config (assuming you have downloaded and compiled and referenced that Microsoft sample):

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <extensions>
      <bindingElementExtensions>
        <add name="customTextMessageEncoding"
             type="Microsoft.ServiceModel.Samples.CustomTextMessageEncodingElement, 
                   Microsoft.ServiceModel.Samples.CustomTextEncoder"/>
      </bindingElementExtensions>
    </extensions>
    <bindings>
      <customBinding>
        <binding name="ISO8859Binding" >
          <customTextMessageEncoding encoding="ISO-8859-1" />
          <httpTransport />
        </binding>
      </customBinding>
    </bindings>

    <client>
      <endpoint name="Test"
                address="......."
                binding="customBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="ISO8859Binding" 
                contract="IYourContract" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

You can find that code, plus a `ISO88591Binding` that basically wraps this whole config into code, on my Skydrive directory [WCF ISO 8859-1 Encoding](http://cid-d06d619dc9f536d4.skydrive.live.com/self.aspx/WCF%20ISO%208859-1%20Encoding/WCF%5E_ISO%5E_8859%5E_1%5E_Encoding.zip). Watch out, though - this is based on my requirements I had at the time, e.g. my service I needed to talk to required https, and also some other a bit whacky settings, so you might need to tweak those or make them configurable in config, if needed. That ISO88591Binding" project also contains a netHttpBinding that again is a Microsoft-provided sample which I used to get the hang of writing my own custom binding in code.

Writing a custom binding in WCF is definitely possible - but not really for the faint of heart....

Comment: If you could post a link to the config and the code, that would be great.  I think this is a serious failing in WCF.

Comment: not really - the whole Internet and SOA world really is based on Unicode standards. In my opinion, even having to deal with ISO-8859-1 is a failing, more than WCF not supporting it out of the box...

Comment: I use CustomTextMessageEncodingElement, but I get error: 
The content type text/xml; charset=ISO-8859-1 of the response message does not match the content type of the binding (text/xml;charset=iso-8859-1). If using a custom encoder, be sure that the IsContentTypeSupported method is implemented properly. The first 1024 bytes of the response were:

Comment: From code of Samples Msdn, I modify constructor from CustomTextMessageEncoder class. replace "{0};charset={1}" by "{0}; charset={1}" (I have included an blank). Then, I get error:The message version of the outgoing message (Soap11 (http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/) AddressingNone 
(http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none)) does not match that of the encoder 

(Soap12 (http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope) Addressing10 (http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing)).
Make sure the binding is configured with the same version as the message.

Comment: In  your sample (Skydrive directory), where is CustomISOBinding.WsgHttpsBindingCollectionElement class ?? It doesn't appears in solution.

Comment: @alhambraeidos: there's a file `ISO88591HttpsBindingCollectionElement.cs` in my solution - that should be the file; sample.config is invalid - that line should be: `<add name="ISO88591HttpsBinding" type="CustomISOBinding.ISO88591HttpsBindingCollectionElement, ISO88591Binding" />` - sorry about that.
      </bindingExtensions>

Comment: Marc, is it possible, and if the answer is "yes" - how, to add the authorization on the http level in your custom binding? I have looked into your solution and could not find such a thing (or I didn't looked in the right place). Thank you.

Comment: Skydrive is empty.

Answer (score 9):

Another option is using the older .NET Framework 2.0 ASMX WebServices technology which supports `iso-8859-1` out of the box:

[image]

[image]

And if the service uses Basic HTTP Authentication you can specify it like this:

```
TheService theService = new TheService();
theService.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
```

Comment: This worked for me for connecting my C# client to php soap server

Comment: This procedure requires less effort, a LOT less, it's also possible to configure everything in the code without needing to edit app.config or web.config, so if you have this code in a library this is easier than other options. It can also be configured with app/web.config if desired.

Answer (score 7):

In this [link](http://www.pathfindertech.net/connecting-to-a-php-web-service-with-wcf-in-c/) you can download the files for make the custom binding, and do the following in your code:

```
CustomBinding binding = new CustomBinding(
   new CustomTextMessageBindingElement("iso-8859-1", "text/xml", MessageVersion.Soap11),
   new HttpTransportBindingElement());

myWebService client = new myWebService();

client.Endpoint.Binding = binding;
```

Comment: Where i need to put this code and downloaded things,i also faced this problem and how solve it

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to deal with tons of downloaded codes and low level implementation you can workaround by using a old style request using HttpWebRequest class, as described [here](http://www.roelvanlisdonk.nl/?p=1893). Now, you will exempt of automatized code and facilities of the Interface and will play with manual Xml parsing.

Answer (score 3):

I know it is an old post but I faced the same issue recently. And some response links are no longer available.

For me, the problem was caused because the server responded with ISO-8859-1 but my Client accepts UTF-8 by default.

**The solution was to create a CustomTextMessageBindingElement that matches with the server configs**:

```
public class CustomTextMessageBindingElement : MessageEncodingBindingElement
{
    public override MessageVersion MessageVersion { get; set; }
    public string MediaType { get; set; }
    public string Encoding { get; set; }

    CustomTextMessageBindingElement(CustomTextMessageBindingElement binding)
        : this(binding.Encoding, binding.MediaType, binding.MessageVersion)
    {
    }

    public CustomTextMessageBindingElement(string encoding, string mediaType,
   MessageVersion messageVersion)
    {
        this.MessageVersion = messageVersion;
        this.MediaType = mediaType;
        this.Encoding = encoding;
    }

    public CustomTextMessageBindingElement(string encoding, MessageVersion messageVersion)
    {
        this.Encoding = encoding;
        this.MessageVersion = messageVersion;
        if (messageVersion.Envelope == EnvelopeVersion.Soap11)
        {
            this.MediaType = "text/xml";
        }
        else if (messageVersion.Envelope == EnvelopeVersion.Soap12)
        {
            this.MediaType = "application/soap+xml";
        }
        else
        {
            this.MediaType = "application/xml";
        }
    }

    public override BindingElement Clone()
    {
        return new CustomTextMessageBindingElement(this);
    }

    public override MessageEncoderFactory CreateMessageEncoderFactory()
    {
        return new CustomTextMessageEncoderFactory(MediaType, Encoding, MessageVersion);
    }

    public override IChannelFactory<TChannel> BuildChannelFactory<TChannel>(BindingContext context)
    {
        if (context == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("context");
        }

        context.BindingParameters.Add(this);
        return context.BuildInnerChannelFactory<TChannel>();
    }
}
public class CustomTextMessageEncoder : MessageEncoder
{
    private CustomTextMessageEncoderFactory factory;
    private XmlWriterSettings writerSettings;
    private string contentType;

    public CustomTextMessageEncoder(CustomTextMessageEncoderFactory factory)
    {
        this.factory = factory;

        this.writerSettings = new XmlWriterSettings();
        this.writerSettings.Encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(factory.CharSet);
        this.contentType = string.Format("{0}; charset={1}",
            this.factory.MediaType, this.writerSettings.Encoding.HeaderName);
    }

    public override bool IsContentTypeSupported(string contentType)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public override string ContentType
    {
        get
        {
            return this.contentType;
        }
    }

    public override string MediaType
    {
        get
        {
            return factory.MediaType;
        }
    }

    public override MessageVersion MessageVersion
    {
        get
        {
            return this.factory.MessageVersion;
        }
    }

    public override Message ReadMessage(ArraySegment<byte> buffer, BufferManager bufferManager, string contentType)
    {
        byte[] msgContents = new byte[buffer.Count];
        Array.Copy(buffer.Array, buffer.Offset, msgContents, 0, msgContents.Length);
        bufferManager.ReturnBuffer(buffer.Array);

        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(msgContents);
        return ReadMessage(stream, int.MaxValue);
    }

    public override Message ReadMessage(Stream stream, int maxSizeOfHeaders, string contentType)
    {
        XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(stream);
        return Message.CreateMessage(reader, maxSizeOfHeaders, this.MessageVersion);
    }

    public override ArraySegment<byte> WriteMessage(Message message, int maxMessageSize, BufferManager bufferManager, int messageOffset)
    {
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
        XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(stream, this.writerSettings);
        message.WriteMessage(writer);
        writer.Close();

        byte[] messageBytes = stream.GetBuffer();
        int messageLength = (int)stream.Position;
        stream.Close();

        int totalLength = messageLength + messageOffset;
        byte[] totalBytes = bufferManager.TakeBuffer(totalLength);
        Array.Copy(messageBytes, 0, totalBytes, messageOffset, messageLength);

        ArraySegment<byte> byteArray = new ArraySegment<byte>(totalBytes, messageOffset, messageLength);
        return byteArray;
    }

    public override void WriteMessage(Message message, Stream stream)
    {
        XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(stream, this.writerSettings);
        message.WriteMessage(writer);
        writer.Close();
    }
}
public class CustomTextMessageEncoderFactory : MessageEncoderFactory
{
    private MessageEncoder encoder;
    private MessageVersion version;
    private string mediaType;
    private string charSet;

    internal CustomTextMessageEncoderFactory(string mediaType, string charSet,
        MessageVersion version)
    {
        this.version = version;
        this.mediaType = mediaType;
        this.charSet = charSet;
        this.encoder = new CustomTextMessageEncoder(this);
    }

    public override MessageEncoder Encoder
    {
        get
        {
            return this.encoder;
        }
    }

    public override MessageVersion MessageVersion
    {
        get
        {
            return this.version;
        }
    }

    internal string MediaType
    {
        get
        {
            return this.mediaType;
        }
    }

    internal string CharSet
    {
        get
        {
            return this.charSet;
        }
    }
}
```

And then create a CustomBinding that use the CustomTextMessageBindingElement:

```
private Binding GetBindConfiguration()
{
    //This configs could be different in Soap server that you are implementing
    //set the soap server config: encoding, mediaType and Soap Version 1.1
    var custom = new CustomTextMessageBindingElement("ISO-8859-1", "text/xml", MessageVersion.CreateVersion(EnvelopeVersion.Soap11, AddressingVersion.None));
    var httpsBindingElement = new HttpsTransportBindingElement()
    {
        MaxReceivedMessageSize = int.MaxValue,
    };

    return new CustomBinding(custom, httpsBindingElement);
}
```

Finaly use the CustomBinding:

```
//Auto generated class using svcutil tool
var clientSoap = new WebService_SigISSPortTypeClient(GetBindConfiguration(), new EndpointAddress(new Uri("https://serverAddress.com.br")));
```

I believe that **this** solution, **should work for .net core** too with little changes and using the new dotnet-svcutil tool

References:
[Implementation of CustomTextMessageEncodingBindingElement](https://success.outsystems.com/Documentation/11/Extensibility_and_Integration/SOAP/Consuming_SOAP_Web_Services/Use_Advanced_Extensibility/Use_a_different_character_encoding)
[Docs for Message Encoder Extensibility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-3.5/ms751486(v=vs.90))