# WCF .Net 4.0 Client Error in deserializing body of reply message

Tags: wcf, encoding, .net-4.0, client, nusoap

I am trying to get a WCF .Net 4.0 client to work with a NuSOAP/0.7.2 (1.94) Web Service.  First thing, the web service is not based on current SOA standards so I had to create a custom encoder to handle the ISO-8859-1 message encoding. When I get the response,  WCF throws the following exception

"Error in deserializing body of reply message"

When looking at the SOAP body, I see `<SOAP-ENV:Body>... stream ...</SOAP-ENV:Body>`

Has anyone come across this error? Any feedback or a point in the right direction would greatly be appreciated. This is my first WCF to "non" WCF service.

```
ApplicationData
TraceData
<DataItem>
<MessageLogTraceRecord Time="2010-07-14T19:14:36.4832868-07:00" Source="TransportReceive" Type="System.ServiceModel.Channels.StreamedMessage" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/ServiceModel/Management/MessageTrace">
<HttpResponse>
<StatusCode>OK</StatusCode>
<StatusDescription>OK</StatusDescription>
<WebHeaders>
<X-SOAP-Server>NuSOAP/0.7.2 (1.94)</X-SOAP-Server>
<Content-Encoding></Content-Encoding>
<Content-Length>496</Content-Length>
<Content-Type>text/xml; charset=ISO-8859-1</Content-Type>
<Date>Thu, 15 Jul 2010 02:14:36 GMT</Date>
<Server>Apache/2.0.54 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.0.54 OpenSSL/0.9.7a PHP/4.3.11</Server>
<X-Powered-By>PHP/4.3.11</X-Powered-By>
</WebHeaders>
</HttpResponse>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:tns="https://www.datatranswebedi.com/soapv2/">
<SOAP-ENV:Header></SOAP-ENV:Header>
<SOAP-ENV:Body>... stream ...</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
</MessageLogTraceRecord>
</DataItem>
</TraceData>
</ApplicationData>
```

Thanks in advance,
Brennan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns there was an error in deserializing the date because it was not in the proper format. I caught the error be enabling "Verbose" debug mode in the WCF client.

System.InvalidCastException: Cannot assign object of type System.Xml.XmlNode[] to an object of type System.DateTime.

The legacy web service was passing back "xsd:date" with a date and time when the data type should have been "xsd:dateTime".

To confirm this was the cause of the problem, I requested two records from the web service and manipulated the XML in the override Message ReadMessage() method and changed the auto generated proxy class. This corrected the problem and I know this not the final solution. Before I contact the author of the legacy web service, does anyone having any comments on the Soap date and dateTime format?

```
Maybe the following date is valid in Soap Version 1.1 with ISO-8859-1 encoding:

<date xsi:type="xsd:date">2010-05-02 08:03:45</date>

 If it is, is this an issue using a custom encoder or was it really the date type/format in the soap body? Microsoft only accepted that date in the following format:

<date xsi:type="xsd:dateTime">2010-05-02T08:03:45</date>


    <customBinding>
      <binding name="ISO8859Binding">
        <customTextMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap11" encoding="ISO-8859-1" mediaType="text/xml"  />
        <httpsTransport />
      </binding>
      </customBinding>

public override Message ReadMessage(Stream stream, int maxSizeOfHeaders, string contentType)
{

    XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(stream);
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();

    // Log to a file.
    StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"C:\dump2.txt");

    doc.Load(reader);
    doc.InnerXml = doc.InnerXml.Replace("xsd:date", "xsd:dateTime");
    doc.InnerXml = doc.InnerXml.Replace("2010-05-02 08:03:45", "2010-05-02T08:03:45");
    doc.InnerXml = doc.InnerXml.Replace("2010-05-02 12:38:06", "2010-05-02T12:38:06");

    sw.WriteLine(doc.InnerXml);
    sw.Flush();
    sw.Close();

    byte[] buffer = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(doc.InnerXml);
    Stream test = new MemoryStream(buffer);
    XmlReader reader2 = XmlReader.Create(test);

    return Message.CreateMessage(reader2, maxSizeOfHeaders, this.MessageVersion);

}
```

Thanks Again,
Brennan

Answer (score 1):

I had to do the same thing (against another legacy type webservice) and I ran into issues at first.

I came across this excellent blog post [WCF: Text Message Encoding and ISO-8859-1 Encoding](http://msmvps.com/blogs/paulomorgado/archive/2007/04/25/wcf-text-message-encoding-and-iso-8859-1-encoding.aspx) which describes a few pitfalls when implementing a custom text encoder for WCF - maybe that'll be helpful to you?

Also check out a previous Stackoverflow question on the same topic:

[Calling a webservice that uses ISO-8859-1 encoding from WCF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1908030/calling-a-webservice-that-uses-iso-8859-1-encoding-from-wcf)