# WCF Exception: Text Message Encoding and ISO-8859-1 Encoding

Tags: c#, wcf, encoding, exception, iso-8859-1

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Calling a webservice that uses ISO-8859-1 encoding from WCF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1908030/calling-a-webservice-that-uses-iso-8859-1-encoding-from-wcf)

I am trying to consume an external Web Service (the web service has PHP implementation) using VS 2008, .net 3.5, WCF( Environment : Windows XP and VS 2008). I add Service Reference to Web Service, VS generates WCF Proxy.

Binding is basicHttpBinding.

I call to method in Web Service, using Proxy, then I started getting a ProtocolException,  I received the following error message :

> System.ServiceModel.ProtocolException:
>   The content type text/xml;
>   charset=ISO-8859-1 of the response
>   message does not match the content
>   type of the binding (text/xml;
>   charset=utf-8). If using a custom
>   encoder, be sure that the
>   IsContentTypeSupported method is
>   implemented properly.
>
> The first 644 bytes of the response were:
>
> This was successful

Well, I needed to call a service in iso-8859-1 encoding.

Any useful sample source code for solve it?

**Update:**

The default encoder used in WCF only works with UTF-8 and UTF-16 (big and little endian).

If I use textEncoding="iso-8859-1" in binding in app.config,

I get this error:

> System.ArgumentException: No se admite
>   la codificación de texto 'iso-8859-1'
>   usada en el formato de mensaje de
>   texto. Nombre del parámetro: encoding.
>
> System.ServiceModel.Channels.TextEncoderDefaults.ValidateEncoding(Encoding
>   encoding)
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.TextMessageEncodingBindingElement.set_WriteEncoding(Encoding
>   value)
>   System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpBinding.set_TextEncoding(Encoding
>   value)
>   System.ServiceModel.Configuration.BasicHttpBindingElement.OnApplyConfiguration(Binding
>   binding)
>   System.ServiceModel.Configuration.StandardBindingElement.ApplyConfiguration(Binding
>   binding)
>   System.ServiceModel.Description.ConfigLoader.LookupBinding(String
>   bindingSectionName, String
>   configurationName, ContextInformation
>   context)
>   System.ServiceModel.Description.ConfigLoader.LoadChannelBehaviors(ServiceEndpoint
>   serviceEndpoint, String
>   configurationName)
>   System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory.ApplyConfiguration(String
>   configurationName)
>   System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory.InitializeEndpoint(String
>   configurationName, EndpointAddress
>   address) ctor(String
>   endpointConfigurationName,
>   EndpointAddress remoteAddress)
>   CreateSimplexFactory()
>   CreateChannelFactory()
>   CreateChannelFactoryRef(EndpointTrait`1
>   endpointTrait)
>   InitializeChannelFactoryRef() ctor()
>   IntegracionEasyVista.ServiceEasyVista.WebServicePortTypeClient..ctor()
>   in

Update:

Calling a web service that uses ISO-8859-1 encoding from WCF

[Calling a webservice that uses ISO-8859-1 encoding from WCF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1908030/calling-a-webservice-that-uses-iso-8859-1-encoding-from-wcf)

This MSDN page (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751486(v=VS.90).aspx) shows how to create a "CustomTextEncoder" which can support more than utf-8, utf-16 and unicode encodings. It includes full sample source code and was very useful for me to get things going.

I use CustomTextMessageEncodingElement, but I get error:

> The content type text/xml; charset=ISO-8859-1 of the response message does not match the content type of the binding (text/xml;charset=iso-8859-1). If using a custom encoder, be sure that the IsContentTypeSupported method is implemented properly. The first 1024 bytes of the response were:**

From code of Samples MSDN, I modify the constructor from CustomTextMessageEncoder class:

```
public CustomTextMessageEncoder(CustomTextMessageEncoderFactory factory)
{
    writerSettings = new XmlWriterSettings();
    writerSettings.Encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(factory.CharSet);
    contentType = string.Format("{0};charset={1}", 
    factory.MediaType, this.writerSettings.Encoding.HeaderName);
}
```

I replace "{0};charset={1}" by "{0}; charset={1}" (I have included an blank)

Then, I get the error:

> The message version of the outgoing message (Soap11 (http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/) AddressingNone 
> (http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none)) does not match that of the encoder 
> (Soap12 (http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope) Addressing10 (http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing)).
>  Make sure the binding is configured with the same version as the message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does this existing answer help? [Calling a webservice that uses ISO-8859-1 encoding from WCF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1908030/calling-a-webservice-that-uses-iso-8859-1-encoding-from-wcf)

Answer (score -2):

I think you should be able to work around this by explicitly changing your binding configuration to set the [textEncoding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731361.aspx) property to "iso-8859-1" instead of the default value of "utf-8".

Comment: Fails for me, in TextEncoderDefaults.ValidateEncoding(Encoding encoding). System.ArgumentException: Not supports textencoding 'iso-8859-1'

Comment: You're right; I hadn't tested it before. Likely some stupid limitation in WCF.

Comment: Maybe better delete this answer.

Comment: Changing the implementation of CustomTextMessageBindingElement constructor sorted it for me                                                                           
    public CustomTextMessageBindingElement()
            : this("ISO-8859-1")
            {
            }

Comment: I using UTF-8 and I still get this error. I searched my code for 8859 and VS does not find it. Yet another misleading error message!