# Why doesn't WCF support other encodings than UTF-8 and UTF-16 by default?

Tags: wcf, soap, encoding, iso-8859-1

We have some issues with a WCF SOAP service that we publish, and is consumed by one of our customers. The issue is that the customer makes SOAP requests encoded as ISO-8859-1, which results in the error message:

> HTTP/1.1 415 Cannot process the message because the content type 'text/xml;charset=iso-8859-1' was not the expected type 'text/xml; charset=utf-8'.

Apparently, WCF only supports UTF-8 and UTF-16 big endian, according to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751486(v=VS.90).aspx. The problem is also discussed in these questions on SO:

- [Calling a webservice that uses ISO-8859-1 encoding from WCF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1908030/calling-a-webservice-that-uses-iso-8859-1-encoding-from-wcf)
- [WCF Exception: Text Message Encoding and ISO-8859-1 Encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4123584/wcf-exception-text-message-encoding-and-iso-8859-1-encoding)

While I agree that unicode is preferred, I'm not in a position to force our customer to change their client, so I will have to fix our service.

It bugs me that I need to put >150 lines of code written by some MSDN author into my project - I can't maintain that code or take responsibility for it. I've also spent quite some time to Google for solutions and try to understand them, which I feel is a waste of time for something that could be handled out of the box by WCF.

**My question is: is there any good reason for Microsoft to implement WCF this way?** Is there a technical reason why SOAP shouldn't use ISO-8859-1? To me, this seems to break Postel's law, rejecting messages that can really be handled by almost any XML parser out there.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, this is allowed in the [SOAP 1.2](http://www.w3.org/TR/soap12-part1/) specification, see section 4.2:

> A binding, if using an XML serialization of the XML infoset, MAY mandate 
>   that a particular character encoding or set of encodings be used.

In this case, WCF chooses to support only UTF-8 and UTF-16, not other encodings.

Answer (score 0):

One workaround is consume the service in an "old times" way using the HttpWebRequest class, as described [here](http://www.roelvanlisdonk.nl/?p=1893). You will have to deal with pure Xml to make requests and other cool things, but works fine!