# ASP.net mvc - Consuming php web service

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-services, soap

I am trying to consume a PHP web service from my ASP.net MVC 3 project, I add a service reference, build ok, but when using it error:

> The content type text/xml; charset=ISO-8859-1 of the response message
>   does not match the content type of the binding (text/xml;
>   charset=utf-8). If using a custom encoder, be sure that the
>   IsContentTypeSupported method is implemented properly

It has to do something with the content type format binding I guess, How would I do it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Solution -> Import the WebService as 'Add Web Reference' instead of 'Add Service Reference', VS does automatically the job.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this question has already been answered, I believe the same concept applies to any type of web service: [WCF Exception: Text Message Encoding and ISO-8859-1 Encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4123584/wcf-exception-text-message-encoding-and-iso-8859-1-encoding)

Comment: Hi, I have been looking about this post, I don' t know much about WCF, I have looked about the proposed solution, seems to me that the Webconfig is not exactly same from Asp.net MVC 3 and WCF solution. What I ends up doing is to import the WebService as 'Add Web Reference' instead of 'Add Service Reference', VS does automatically the job, works fine now