# Change WCF Response encoding

Tags: c#, wcf, rest, encoding, iso-8859-1

I have a WCF service who must now send data in this encoding : iso-8859-1.

I tried to change IIS configguration or add globalization balise in the config but the response of the service is always on UTF-8.

Can somebody help me ?

Thanks.

Comment: We are working toward implementing downloading CSV file over WCF REST.  The file is saved as BOM UTF-8. But when opened in MS Excel, it ignores the BOM and renders Degree symbols (°) as "Â°".  Trying everything we can to change the encoding.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this out of the box in WCF. See this answer for some details on how to create a custom binding that will support ISO-8859-1: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1908154/2420979

Comment: I see it but it talks more about using a service who is with iso-8859-1 encoding but i'm trying to expose a service who works like that.

Comment: A binding can be placed on a client or host... In this case you'd want to use the same binding for your service host.

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded the CustomTextMessageEncoder for the framework 4.0, i succeeded to display the svc page but all my calls returns nothing and the HELP balise don't display for the rest service.

I noticed also that when i call my local service it executes the method twice without final result but if i change the binding into a webHttpBinding i execute the method one time and it works

Here is my config :

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="TestTheIso.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehaviour">
        <endpoint  binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="DefaultBinding"   contract="TestTheIso.IService1" behaviorConfiguration="toto">
        </endpoint>
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <customBinding>
        <binding name="DefaultBinding">
          <customTextMessageEncoding encoding="ISO-8859-1" messageVersion="None" />
          <httpTransport manualAddressing="true"/>
        </binding>
      </customBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ServiceBehaviour">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="toto">
          <webHttp helpEnabled="true" automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="false" defaultOutgoingResponseFormat="Json" />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    <extensions>
      <bindingElementExtensions>
        <add name="customTextMessageEncoding"
             type="Microsoft.Samples.CustomTextMessageEncoder.CustomTextMessageEncodingElement, CustomTextMessageEncoder"/>
      </bindingElementExtensions>
    </extensions>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```