# WCF - How to serialize and deserialize in ISO8583?

Tags: c#, wcf, serialization, iso8583, openiso8583.net

I'm working on a financial application that use WCF Services to communicate to clients. I want to connect my application to a global bank network in my country and I must use ISO8583 Messages to connect to it. is WCF suitable for this scenario? how can serialize and deserialize messages in ISO8583 in WCF?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WCF is totally suitable for this scenario. You must write a Custom Text Message Encoder to handle ISO8593 encoding.

Here is an example on how to do it:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms751486%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Here is another example using a different enconding, ISO8859, but it's the same context:
[Calling a webservice that uses ISO-8859-1 encoding from WCF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1908030/calling-a-webservice-that-uses-iso-8859-1-encoding-from-wcf)